# Is there a free copy of this early (earliest?) siddur online?

Tags: internet, prayer-book, geonim

A footnote in the Rosenfeld selichot book said Rav Amram Gaon was approached by Spanish Jews in the 800's with a request to allow the writing down the daily prayers, something that was prohibited by the gemara ([Shabbat 115a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=115&format=pdf)).

Is there a copy of this siddur on the web (ideally for free)?

I found what seems to be his siddur for sale here
http://www.moznaim.com/siddur-rav-amram-gaon.html

Comment: *The Talmudic citation is **Shabbat 115b**, not 115a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seder Rav Amram Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amram_Gaon#Seder_Rav_Amram) can be found on Hebrewbooks.org for free in two pdfs: [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/14438) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/14439).

Comment: You may wish to defend (alternatively retract) your answer in light of the other.

Comment: That is the Aryeh Leib Frumkin edition. There is also the N.N. Coronel edition, available at HebrewBooks ([part 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/43020) and [part 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/43019)), and at [daat.ac.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=24) (in multiple PDFs).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the text as he wrote it has been lost. The text available today has been very heavily edited to agree with local custom. This is evidenced by manuscripts which differ drastically from each other and rulings of his which run contra to the modern text. The earliest siddur we have is the one of saadia gaon, however, we don't have a complete book, and what we do have was found in a genizah. The earliest complete siddur with any kind of mesorah is found in the mishneh torah.