# How does the earliest written siddur compare w siddurim of today?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book

How does the davening in the siddurim of Rav Amram Gaon (who gave us the earliest written siddur, [Is there a free copy of this early (earliest?) siddur online?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63887/is-there-a-free-copy-of-this-early-earliest-siddur-online/63889#63889)) compare with siddurim of today?

Alternatively, is there a publication (preferably in English) that compares their content with respect to the prayers included.

Comment: From what I'm noticing, much of Siddur Rav Amram Ga;on became Nusach Ashkenaz. I notice this esp. in his phrasing in Kedusha. Nusach Sefard (aka - Nusach Ari) seems to have developed far later. I'm not sure as to where its wording, ordering and phrasing originated. Need a bit more research.

Comment: A comment in a machzor said that rav amram gaon's machzor for YK did not include kol nidrei.  He (and the academies of Babalon) were against kol nidre. This makes me think that rabbis of today have more clout than back then.

Comment: Kol Nidre has a fascinating history. In a sense, your comment has some validity spec. regarding Kol Nidre. Fairly recently there was a major push by the Reform (and, perhaps Conservative) movement to eliminate it as it was considered "archaic". If you have access to the Hertz Chumash, view notes at end of Bamidabr where he discusses vows and its relation to *Kol Nidre* and its history. In short, it was decided to include it largely b/x of its association w/ Marranos, from my understanding. I don't know if your "clout" statement would apply as a general rule to much of tefillah, overall.

Comment: According to endnote 12 [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20689476?seq=14#page_scan_tab_contents), the closest thing to a critical edition of Rav Amram's _sidur_ is [that of Daniel Goldschmidt (1971)](http://www.worldcat.org/title/seder-rav-amram-gaon-arukh-u-mugah-al-pi-kitve-yad-u-defusim-im-hashlamot-shinuye-nushaot-u-mavo/oclc/19187030), which is neither online nor in English. Unfortunately, the author notes "None of these editions can be considered critical editions . . . and it is doubtful whether this can be done."