# What is the earliest Ashkenaz siddur and where might I find a copy?

Tags: internet, prayer-book, ashkenazi

The earliest sefardic siddur dates back to the 800's, see [Is there a free copy of this early (earliest?) siddur online?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63887/is-there-a-free-copy-of-this-early-earliest-siddur-online).  What is the oldest ashkenaz siddur, and it is available on the web or for purchase?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that Siddur resembles Sefardi Nusach more than Ashkenazi Nusach?

Comment: I think the earliest Siddur which seems to follow what is now "Nusach Ashkenaz" is Siddur Rav Maram Ga'on. It's online in hebrewbooks.com. You can prob. find a copy ina good Judaica store as well.

Comment: @DanF, According to Wikipedia, R' Amram Gaon's siddur is actually corrupt. Unlike the Rasa"g's siddur, no manuscript dates back to the geonic period *or* Bavel. As such, depending on the edition, Seder R' Amram Gaon could end up looking like any one of a variety of Rishonic siddurim.

Comment: Courtesy ping @DoubleAA ^

Comment: I believe the earliest Ashkenazi siddurim are Siddur Rashi and the Machzor Vitry. The author of the latter was a talmid of Rashi's and IIRC, incorporates many of his rav's usages.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Well, it is conjecture, as follows.  The Jews of Spain asked to be able to write down the siddur. Presumably, the resulting siddur reflected their practice.  We also know that Rav Amram Gaon was in the Sura Academy in Babylonia. I do not know if that tells us anything germane to the question you posed.

Comment: http://www.magnespress.co.il/Book/%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%94.aspx?name=%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94+%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%94&code=45-131084

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt, but that means that the earliest Ashknazi siddur might be an Ashkenazi edition of Seder R Amaram Gaon.

Comment: As seen in the comments to Mike's answer, this question has no answer. Drawing a line between Nusach Ashkenaz and its predecessor nusachos in France and North Italy is kind of arbitrary. Evolution is gradual.

Comment: @YehudaW, Siddur Ezor Eliyahu is Nusach haGra. But, they made it by doing manuscript reresearch and then laying the Gra's changes on top of that. Unwinding all the changes made by publishers and the maskilim hired to "fix" the diqduq. Its footnotes, therefore, are a fairly good source of earlier Ashkenazi nusach, often noting regional variations. (Old Poland vs. Prague vs. Germany, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Machzor Vitry* by Rabbi Simcha ben Shmuel of Vitry](http://datab.us/i/Machzor%20Vitry) was written around the year 1100.  It is not only a high-holiday machzor, but also contains the services for weekdays, Shabbat, and festivals, and customs and laws following the rulings of Rashi.  Rav Simcha was a talmid of Rashi, and the machzor reflects the customs of Jews in early medieval France.  This is believed to be the basis for Nusach Ashkenaz.  A two-volume printed edition of it can be purchased [here](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?P_ID=3082&strPageHistory=related) (it says three volumes, but I think it is really two).  An online edition can be found [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/10172).  Be warned though that some manuscripts and printed editions of this book have extraneous material added in and do not mark those as later additions not by Rav Simcha.

Comment: This is Nusach Tsarfat, which is close to, but not the same as, Nusach Ashkenaz.