# Origins of "Kaddish Yachid"

Tags: tefilla, kaddish, geonim

I was recently introduced to the concept of a "Kaddish Yachid," attributed to Rav Amram Gaon. A few fairly unreliable sources online discuss it as some form of a stand-in for when Kaddish can't be said in a minyan (ex. [1](https://images.shulcloud.com/1288/uploads/CMS-Pages/Spiritual-Life/In-Times-of-Needweb.pdf), [2](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/corona-kaddish/)), and the person who originally introduced it to me only had its text and authorship.

However, when I try to search through the [Seder of Rav Amram Gaon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/63889/9682) for this, I can't find any reference to this.

If this was actually written by Rav Amram Gaon, where can I find it in his writings? If not, who *actually* wrote it, and where?

Comment: Just because it's in Seder Rav Amram Gaon doesn't mean he wrote it (or even included it in his original letter). In fact, it's omitted in Daniel Goldschmidt's critical edition, AFAICT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be found where you mentioned in [Siddur Rav Amram Gaon](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43020&st=&pgnum=14). He also brings a barchu l'yachid on next page.

For further info and more opinions see the Darkei Moshe Ha'Aruch 59: 3

Text:

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this Darkei Moshe?

Comment: In my Tur/SA its found at the end of the Tur

Comment: Beis Yosef cites a Rokach that held this way as well.